# How to save image url with Room library

Tags: android, android-room

I'm implementing Room Library. I'm trying to load an `url` to show an image inside an `Image view` inside a `Card view` to show a product info. I would like to sava those url in my app.

I tried a few thinks with not success. I have an object class called `Products` with a few characteristics, one of them is an image.

At this point, with the knowledge I have (basic), a been trying things to see what happens. I think its pointless to write them because are pretty foolish.

Can someone explain my how to do it?

I indeed tried looking for answers but found nothing useful to my case.
Thank you

Comment: for each `url` create a `product` object and save that using `room`. The [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

you should save your images url's in your database. And when your application run you can load these. Or you could save your image as bitmap but if you do this your queries going to run very slow.

Just save urls as string that's all.